# Intersection of an ellipsoid and plane in parametric form

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

I want to find the parametric equation of the ellipse in 3d space which is formed by the intersection of a known ellipsoid and a known plane. The ellipsoid has the Cartesian equation: $(x/a)^2+(y/b)^2+(z/a)^2=1$. 
While the plane has the equation: $mx+ny+kz=0$. I have substituted one equation in the other but what I get is an elliptical cylinder since I had eliminated the $z$-components. How can I get the exact equation of the ellipse of intersection in parametric form?

Comment: Did you mean for two of the half-axis lengths to be the same?

Comment: Yes because I was thinking of the ellipsoid to be a model of the Earth.

Comment: How do know that a given intersection of a plane with an ellipsoid is indeed an ellipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Find vectors of the semiaxes of the ellipse, meaning find (x,y,z) which satisfies both equations and its length is longest(shortest).
$$(x/a)^2+(y/b)^2+(z/a)^2=1$$
$$mx+ny+kz=0$$
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=\min \lor \max$$
And then parametric equation will be $(x,y,z)=\vec v_1\sin \theta+\vec v_2\cos \theta$

**Edit - More than a hint**
As yota suggested this hint isn't too helpful since problem is still hard to solve I will try to push it till the end:

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=x^2+y^2+z^2-a^2((x/a)^2+(y/b)^2+(z/a)^2-1)=y^2(1-a^2/b^2)+a^2$$
As we can see one of the semiaxes vectors has $y$ coordinate equal to $0$, since the expression above reaches its max/min when $y=0$

We can put it in the equations to find $x$ and $z$:
$$z=-mx/k$$
$$(x/a)^2+(-mx/k/a)^2=1$$
$$x^2k^2+x^2m^2=k^2a^2$$
$$x^2=k^2a^2/(k^2+m^2)$$
So we have one semiaxis $v_1=(ka/\sqrt{k^2+m^2},0,-ma/\sqrt{k^2+m^2})$

Another should be colinear to $v_1\times(m,n,k)$ or even better $(k,0,-m)\times(m,n,k)$ which is:
$$v_2=t(mn,-m^2-k^2,kn)$$
where
$$t=1/\sqrt{(mn/a)^2+((m^2+k^2)/b)^2+(kn/a)^2}$$

Comment: without anymore details, I'm stuck at trying to find the min/max values of $$ \left(\sqrt{\frac{b^2 c^2 k^2 \left(a^2 \left(b^2 n^2+c^2 k^2\right)-x^2 \left(a^2 m^2+b^2 n^2+c^2 k^2\right)\right)}{a^2 \left(b^2 n^2+c^2 k^2\right)^2}}+\frac{b^2 m n x}{b^2 n^2+c^2 k^2}\right)^2+\frac{\left(\frac{c^2 k^2 m x}{b^2 n^2+c^2 k^2}-n \sqrt{\frac{b^2 c^2 k^2 \left(a^2 \left(b^2 n^2+c^2 k^2\right)-x^2 \left(a^2 m^2+b^2 n^2+c^2 k^2\right)\right)}{a^2 \left(b^2 n^2+c^2 k^2\right)^2}}\right)^2}{k^2}+x^2 $$... what a mess :D

Comment: try switching to polar coordinates

Comment: well... I'm not doing my homework (^o^);

Comment: @yota haha, i'm not going to calculate that, whether it's your homework or not

Comment: A position I understand :) yet, your hints are sibyllin... And in spherical coordinates it looks even worse :D (can't put it in comments, its too long)

Comment: There it is @yota, not so disasterous as it seemed

Comment: ^3^ thanks, I check that :)

Comment: your solution is not correct, the point defined as a combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$ is on the plane but not on the ellipsoid : https://github.com/yota-code/goto.wgs84/blob/master/notebook/stackexchange_djura.ipynb I'll share my attempt as soon as it is ready :)

Comment: @yota aha, possibly I didn't calculate it correctly, but the procedure is correct so you are free to find the mistake :D

Comment: @yota I checked your code, you have $b^4$ there instead $b^2$

Comment: Crap ! I feel ashamed for this one... I still don't understand why my attempts are much more complexes... ashamed and perplexed :D

Comment: $x^2+y^2+z^2=x^2+y^2+z^2-a^2((x/a)^2+(y/b)^2+(z/a)^2-1)$ looks like magic O_o

Comment: @yota it is a standard way to solve conditional...extremes or whatever.. Anyway, good luck with it, glad if it worked